# Membership of synced on-premise active directory group in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online

How do I get the membership of an on-premise active directory group that is synced to our Office 365 tenant?

This appears to be possible as the third-party application Sharegate shows me the membership of the group.

I am currently using Powershell and the `Get-SPOUser` cmdlet which includes the AD group name and SID in the results. I would like to be able to expand this group to get the full membership.